How to assign a constant to be the type of one of the keys from another type?
I have a type such as this:
export type datasetResponse = {
  address_1?: string;
  address_2?: string;
  city?: string;
};

And in my application I am passing a state around called clickedItem. clickedItem is either address_1, address_2 or city. Here is where the issue comes in. There is an error that says Property 'clickedFilterItem' does not exist on type 'datasetResponse'.
export default function DatasetFilterItems({
  data,
  clickedItem,
}: DatasetChildrenFilterItemsProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const clickedFilterItem = clickedItem
  const filteredList = peopleData.map((data) => data.clickedFilterItem); //Property 'clickedFilterItem' does not exist on type 'datasetResponse'.

clickedItem is definitely one of the dataResponse keys but since it's not explicitly in the type I get an error. Does anyone know a good solution to this problem?

Is "clickedFilterItem" the specific field you need to access, or are you trying to use the variable clickedFilterItem to determine which field you want to access? Because if it's the latter, you need to do data[clickedFilterItem] instead of data.clickedFilterItem.

ahhh yes it was const clickedFilterItem = clickedChildrenItem as keyof peopleDatasetResponse;
const filteredList = peopleData.map((data) => data[clickedFilterItem]);

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] (e.g., what's DatasetChildrenFilterItemsProps? what's peopleData) including any imports you need for the code to demonstrate your issue when people copy and paste it into their own IDEs.

If you're facing an issue where clickedItem is a key from datasetResponse but TypeScript isn't recognizing it dynamically, you can use a type assertion to handle this. Here's how you can solve this problem:
Solution:
You can use TypeScript's index signatures to dynamically access the properties.
export default function DatasetFilterItems({
  data,
  clickedItem,
}: DatasetChildrenFilterItemsProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  
  const filteredList = peopleData.map((data) => data[clickedItem as keyof datasetResponse]);

  return (
    <div>
      {filteredList.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>{item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

or you can go like this
type DatasetChildrenFilterItemsProps = {
 data: datasetResponse[]; 
clickedItem: keyof datasetResponse;
}

